# PYTHON REQUESTS ERROR: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get data from a web service,working with soap. Until now, I was able to get successfull responses but now my code throws this error. Any ideas on why a working code a day before throws this error now?
Note that this is not a public API, your IP needed to be in whitelist to retrieve data.

edit for code:

```
import requests
headers = {'x-ibm-client-id': "MY KEY",
       'content-type': 'application/soap+xml',
       'accept':'application/xml'}

url="https://api.epias.com.tr/epias/exchange/electricity/balancingMarket"
login="""<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username>string</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password>string</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="string">string</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>string</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
   <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="string">
    <wsu:Created>string</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>string</wsu:Expires>
   </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <dgp:login xmlns:dgp="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com"><!-- mandatory -->
   <loginMessage>
    <Password v="MYPASSWORD"></Password>
    <UserName v="MYUSERNAME"></UserName>
   </loginMessage>
  </dgp:login>
 </soapenv:Body>
 """
s=requests.Session()

s.get(url)
res=s.post(url,data=login,headers=headers)
```

Comment: It's not you, it's the web service. It is shutting down the connection you established. It doesn't like you any more.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code block where you call the web service too?

Comment: Any idea why this happens. Because same issue was occured for another product of them as well but I fixed it in a way. I don't know why it worked but changing http to https in url solved my problem. On the other hand, that solution kind thing did not worked for this product.

Comment: have you tried to change proxy settings?

Comment: No, I don't. And sadly, I have no idea how to do that and how this can help on problem.

Answer (score 2):

keep the above code ,you should handle the proxy setting.

```
import urlparse,urllib2


s=requests.Session()
opener=urllib2.build_opener()
if proxy:

    proxy_params={urlparse.urlparse(url).scheme : proxy}
    opener.add_handler(urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy_params))
s.get(url)
res=s.post(url,data=login,headers=headers)
```

if your code used to work, the site might have blocked your IP or don't like your header settings.